# AWS Glue crawled the tables in Redshift schema in the wrong order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, database-schema, aws-glue

I created a JDBC connection in Glue crawler to read the schema from my Redshift table. The crawler crawled the Redshift columns, but it created a table with incorrect column order in the Glue Data catalog. For example column zip is the 1000th column in Redshift schema but it appears as the 5th column. Since there are 1200 columns and we do not want to use additional software to handle the schema separately, the incorrect column order is a big hurdle.
My goal is to load data (without headers) from S3 to Redshift table that I already created.
Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks!